# searchkick 400 Searchkick::InvalidQueryError for suggestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Someone is having this kind of problem with searchkick? I did something wrong?

article.rb

```
searchkick suggest: [:status]
scope :search_import, -> { includes(:author, :medium, :tags) }
has_many :article_tags
has_many :tags, through: :article_tags
belongs_to :author
belongs_to :medium
```

article_controller.rb

```
def search_article
   result_articles = Article.search params[:search],
                                 suggest: true,
                                 fields: %i[title body author.name status],
                                 page: params[:page],
                                 per_page: params[:per_page]


   render json: { result_articles: result_articles , time: result_articles.took, suggestion: 
   result_articles.suggestions }

 end
```

> Searchkick::InvalidQueryError ([400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [status.suggest]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"articles_development_20200918194930310","node":"hVbRSnSiQGW6xSM7pG-36A","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [status.suggest]"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [status.suggest]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [status.suggest]"}}},"status":400}):

Answer (score 1):

```
fields: %i[title body author.name status]
```

translated to

```
fields: [:title, :body, :"author.name", :status]
```

did you noticed `:"author.name"`? there will not be such column for sure in your DB.

If you are looking to search by `author`'s name assuming an `article` has one `author`, you need to index it as a filed like `author_name` in your `search_data` method in the `Article` model and then you will be able to search it using

```
fields: %i[title body author_name status]
```

Comment: thanx for your response, my problem is with suggessionts and not with author_name